# RecycleView with Internal storage images

Tags: java, android

I'm making app that's using integrated camera, saving images in internal storage and then it should be displayed in fragment via RecycleView as a 3 images in a row.

This method is for saving images:

```
private String saveToInternalStorage(Bitmap bitmapImage){
    File mypath, f;
    ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
    File directory = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
    f = new File("/data/user/0/androidappspractice.com.photomap/app_imageDir", "0.png");
    if(f.exists()) {
        int nameNumber = 0;
        while(f.exists()){
            nameNumber++;
            f = new File("/data/user/0/androidappspractice.com.photomap/app_imageDir", String.format("%s.png", nameNumber));
        }
        mypath = new File(directory, String.format("%s.png", nameNumber));
    } else {
        mypath = new File(directory, "0.png");
    }

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
        bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

I can't figure it out how to make an adapter that will do such thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as it concerns the adapter try this adapter, 
first before you create it set a layout manager for it and it will show you every 3 images in  a single row :

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(context,3);
    RecyclerView recyclerView  = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

than create an xml to inflate it later inside the adapter we name it as inflation.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

than create your adapter :

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.myViewHolder> {


        Context ctx;
        //this is your images

        List<Bitmap> myImages;

        Adapter(Context context, List<Bitmap> images) {

            this.ctx = context;
            this.myImages = images;
        }


        @Override
        public Adapter.myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.inflation, parent, false);

            return new myViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(Adapter.myViewHolder holder, int position) {

                holder.image.setImageBitmap(myImages.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return myImages.size();
        }

        class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            ImageView image;



            public myViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            }


        }


    }
```

and set your adapter to your recyclerView

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this, "//your data" )
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

hope this will help .

Comment: I've set it up and so far so good. But I have one more question for my data should I take all images from internal storage folder, loop them and put in a list as bitmaps and then set it as Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getContext(), myListofBitmaps);

Comment: yeap that will work , or you can feed the adapter with any method you want , just , modify the onBindViewHolder accordingly